# Changing Colors on Crystal Report using code in C# ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, crystal-reports

I have created a report in Crystal Report. It has this code that works just fine but I have 1 problem. For example if Remarks field is "A" it should color remarks as "red" and if result is "B" it should color remarks as "Blue". Can you please assist me. Here's my code.

```
SqlConnection cnn;
string connectionString = null;
string sql = null;
connectionString = "data source=Server; initial catalog=Database1;user id=sa; password= passw0rd";
cnn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
cnn.Open();
sql = "select Date as DataColumn1, Name as DataColumn2, Year as DataColumn3 Remarks as DataColumn4 from TableStudents";
SqlDataAdapter dscmd = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, cnn);
cnn.Close();

DataSet1 ds = new DataSet1();
dscmd.Fill(ds, "DataTable1");

CrystalReport1 objRpt = new CrystalReport1();
objRpt.SetDataSource(ds.Tables[0]);

objRpt.ExportToDisk(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, Server.MapPath("Reports.pdf"));
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(base.Page, base.Page.GetType(), "check0", "window.open('" + "Reports.pdf" + "','win2','status=no,toolbar=no,scrollbars=no,titlebar=no,menubar=no,resizable=yes,directories=no,location=no');", true);
```

This code will open the report on new window perfectly. Just a problem with changing colors. I don't have any idea. Please tell me what to do. This is the simple concept but i dont know what to do next. Thanks.

```
if(result=="A")
{
result.color = "red";
}
else
{
result.color = "blue";
}
```

Comment: I havent worked in ASP .net crystal reports, but I believe that they will be same, in the report preview, can you right click the field and check its properties, do you see a formula icon in front of the background color property? waiting

Answer (score 1):

i can't get your idea about result but i suppose you got a field object and you want to change color based on changing that field object
there for the code is:

```
            foreach (Section sec in report1.Sections)
            {
                for (int i = 1; i < sec.ReportObjects.Count + 1; i++)
                {
                    objMain = report1.Sections[sec.Name].ReportObjects[i];
                    try
                        {
                            FieldObject to1 = (FieldObject)objMain;
                            if(to1.Value == "A")
                            {                                
                                to1.TextColor = ColorToUInt(Color.Red);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                to1.TextColor = ColorToUInt(Color.Blue);
                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception){}
                }                
            }
```

and finally you must add this method too:

```
    public uint ColorToUInt(Color color)
    {
        return (uint)((color.A << 24) | (color.R << 16) |
        (color.G << 8) | (color.B << 0));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered these links:

[Change Font Color Dynamically 1](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?236397-%2a%2aRESOLVED%2a%2aDynamically-Change-TextColor-of-Formula-in-Crystal-Reports)

[Change Font Color Dynamically 2](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/135e4d33-c32c-4961-ab39-3bdf8df91e12/change-font-color-with-condition)